# Issue in inserting bulk data in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, callback

Here is my object,

```
{'name': 'Lipika', 'monday': 1}
{'name': 'Ram', 'monday': 0}
{'name': 'Lipika', 'tuesday': 1}
{'name': 'Ram', 'tuesday': 0}
```

**Here is the two condition**

I want to check whether Lipika is present in the DB, If not present i should create his name in the User Collection and then insert in the Attendance Collection, If Already present then i should just insert the Attendance  Collection.

**Here is what i have tried**

```
for (var key in row) {
checkUser(name,function(data) {
//Insert inside Attendence collection then..
});
}


function checkUser(name, callback){
  dbModel.User.findOne({ name: name}, function (err, data) {
    if(data){
        callback('exist');
    }else{
        var User = new dbModel.User({name : name});
        User.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Err',err);
        } else {
            callback('not exist');
        }
        }); 
    }
  });
}
```

But it is creating Lipika and Ram two times as nodejs run async way. How can i wait the until the javascript checks and insert inside the user ?

Comment: are you passing lipika and ram two times?

Comment: Yes, as it has two times in the object

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may be help you !

```
 function checkUser(name, callback){
      dbModel.User.findOne({ name: name}).then((data)=>{
        if(data){
            //callback('exist');
        //user already present insert attendance
        }else{
            var User = new dbModel.User({name : name});
            User.save().then((data)=>{
            //user not present insert collection
            },(err)={

            });
        }
    },(error)=>{
        console.log('something went wrong');
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of everytime checking in DB why don't you make name field unique, That will give the more accurate result. Because Reading and writing will create the problem if multiple requests will come at same time.

Use [findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) to avoid 2 operation reading and writing. Not Good approach :(

```
dbModel.User.findAndModify({
    query: {
        name: name
    },
    update: {
        $setOnInsert: {
            name: name
        }
    },
    new: true,
    upsert: true
}, (err, data) => {
    callback('exist');
});
```